# javalite Activeweb how to get response body string for logging purpose in HttpSupportFilter

Tags: javalite, activeweb

How to get **responseBody** string for logging purpose in **HttpSupportFilter**?

Common log solution is create wrapper and insert it to the standar filter

If we use standar filter we cannot access activejdbc db connection layer

I tried to apply wrapper but it does not work, the string is still empty

```
public class HTTPLogFilter extends HttpSupportFilter {

    private static ThreadLocal<Long> start = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    @Override
    public void before() {
        start.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void after() {

        if(Configuration.HTTPLOGS_ENABLE) {

            Registry.instance().getStatisticsQueue().enqueue(
                    new QueryExecutionEvent(getRoute().getController().getClass().getName() +
                            "#" + getRoute().getActionName() + ":" + method(), System.currentTimeMillis() - start.get()));

            HttpLog httpLog = new HttpLog();

            String username ="TEST";

            Map request = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            request.put("requestUrl", url());
            request.put("contextPath", context());
            request.put("uriFullPath", uri());
            request.put("uriPath", path());
            request.put("method", method());
            request.put("requestHeaders", headers());
            request.put("requestParams", params());
            request.put("queryString", queryString());
            request.put("requestBody", getRequestString());

            Map response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            response.put("responseHeaders", getResponseHeaders());
            try {
                // BUG ! this responseBody still empty
                response.put("responseBody", getHttpServletResponse().getWriter().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            httpLog.setCreatedby(username);
            httpLog.setCreateddt(new Date());
            httpLog.setUsername(username);
            String remoteAddr = ipForwardedFor() != null ? ipForwardedFor() : remoteAddress();
            httpLog.setIpaddress(remoteAddr );
            httpLog.setUseragent(userAgent());
            httpLog.setControllername(getRoute().getController().getClass().getName() + "." + getRoute().getActionName());
            httpLog.setHttpmethod(method());
            httpLog.setHttpexceptions("");
            httpLog.setExecutiondt(new Date(start.get()));
            httpLog.setExecutiondur(System.currentTimeMillis() - start.get());
            httpLog.setHttpurl(url());
            httpLog.setHttprequest(JsonHelper.toJson(request));
            httpLog.setHttpresponse(JsonHelper.toJson(response));
            httpLog.setHttpstatuscode(getHttpServletResponse().getStatus());
            httpLog.saveIt();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally, you are on the  right path. It is my understanding that `HttpLog` is a model, and you want to store the request   values that to database, correct?

You write:

*if we use standar filter we cannot access activejdbc db connection layer*

So, the ActiveWeb filters have ordering, which is  documented here: https://javalite.io/controller_filters#filter-ordering

This means  that if you want a database connection available in the `HTTPLogFilter`, you  have to register the `DBConnectionFilter` before the `HTTPLogFilter`, example:

```
public class AppControllerConfig extends AbstractControllerConfig {
    public void init(AppContext appContext) {
        add(new DBConnectionFilter(), new HTTPLogFilter());
    }
}
```

This way, the `DBConnectionFilter.before()` will be called before the `HTTPLogFilter.before()`  and will open a DB connection accordingly.

On  the side note: you will be filling your database pretty quickly, and a recommendation is to simply log all this data to a log file and use a log analyzer like Splunk or Graylog.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion 

Yes correct HttpLog is a model 
Yes I have already use this         
  add(new DBConnectionFilter(), new HTTPLogFilter());

Ok after trying this 
- on normal ( exception not occured ) this filter ordering works because DB connection is not yet closed by the DBConnectionFilter() after() method / onException() method
- on exception occured , it seems the on onExceptions on DBConnectionFilter() will be triggered and database will be close 
  which will lead to DB connection not exist error on HTTPLogFilter

Comment: so i added this on HTTPLogFilter after() and onException() 
         if(isDBConnectionExists())
            createHttpLog();
and problem on DB connection solved 

What about the issue on responseBody ? is it possible to get the responseBody string/ bytearray after the outputsteam is closed using activeweb filter ?

Comment: I do not  think you can do that because the  content already streamed to a client, this is just Servlet level